# Python convert a bytearray to hex array

Tags: python, arrays

Here is what I am trying to do:

given the bytearray bellow:

bytearray(b'\xc0\x00\x00\xfe\xb4\xf0\xfe\xb4\xb0\xfe\xb4\xce\xfe\xb4l\xfe\xb6\x8fxfe\xb56\xfe\xb5u\xfe\xb4\xb1')

Pls:

making it into a new array like [0xC00000, 0xFEB4F0, ...]

Comment: you have 24bit floating point numbers? what's the format?

Comment: So where is the floating point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import binascii
x = bytearray(b'\xc0\x00\x00\xfe\xb4\xf0\xfe\xb4\xb0\xfe\xb4\xce\xfe\xb4l\xfe\xb6\x8fxfe\xb56\xfe\xb5u\xfe\xb4\xb1')

[binascii.hexlify(x[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]
```

yields the list of hex-strings:

```
['c00000', 'feb4f0', 'feb4b0', 'feb4ce', 'feb46c', 'feb68f', '786665', 
 'b536fe', 'b575fe', 'b4b1']
```

The list you asked for,

```
[0xC00000, 0xFEB4F0, ...]
```

is a list of `int`s, since, for example, 0xC00000 is simply an `int` represented in hexadecimals:

```
In [7]: 0xC00000
Out[7]: 12582912
```

In Python2, you could obtain that list of `int`s by using `int(hexstring, 16)`:

```
>>> [int(binascii.hexlify(x[i:i+3]), 16) for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]
[12582912, 16692464, 16692400, 16692430, 16692332, 16692879, 7890533,
 11876094, 11892222, 46257]
```

Or, in Python3,

```
>>> [int.from_bytes(x[i:i+3], 'big', signed=False) for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]
[12582912, 16692464, 16692400, 16692430, 16692332, 16692879, 7890533, 
 11876094, 11892222, 46257]
```

Comment: Is there any way to add ‘0x’ before each string？

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to just use string formatting: `['0x{}'.format(binascii.hexlify(x[i:i+3]).upper()) for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]`.

Comment: `'{:#x}'.format(int(binascii.hexlify(x[i:i+3]), 16))` is also possible, but slower due to the conversion from string to int and back to string.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [(a<<16)+(b<<8)+c for a,b,c in zip(*[iter(bytes[3:])]*3)]
[16692464, 16692400, 16692430, 16692332, 16692879, 16692534, 16692597, 16692401]
```

Comment: Too terse. Please explain or expand.